# If statement not working comparing Outlook sender with existing dataframe entry

Tags: python, outlook

I am new to Python. I am scanning Outlook inbox looking for a specific subject (YES). If I find that subject, get the sender email and check if  that sender is in my emailing list, if not, add them to my emailing list.

I am stuck with the IF statement comparing the sender with what I have in my dataframe. EmailList.xlsx has 1 column "Name" and 8 entries "LastName, FirstName I"

```
import win32com.client
import os
import pandas as pd

get_path = os.getcwd()
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items

EmailList = (pd.read_excel("EmailList.xlsx", sheet_name='ABC', index_col=0))

EmailList.info() #<<-- I can see my dataframe, column name and number of entries.

a=len(messages)
if a > 0:
    for messages2 in messages:
        subject = messages2.Subject

        if "YES" in subject:
            sender = messages2.Sender
            print(subject) #<<-- Works fine, I see the subject
            print(sender) #<<-- Works fine, I see the sender

            if EmailList ['Name'] == sender: <<-- does not work
            if EmailList ['Name'].str.contains(sender).any(): <<-- does not work
                print("Your are already subscribed")

            else:
             print("append DF")
```

Any ideas? I am guessing there is something with the "sender" string, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: under your `print(sender)` try `print(EmailList['Name'])` to see if they are same, also you can check the `type` to see if its matching

Comment: Thank you mtkilic.
that does print my DF with the output I expect.

As soon as I hit the IF statement, I get for 

if EmailList ['Name'] == sender:

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

For 
if EmailList['Name'].str.contains(sender).any():

TypeError: unhashable type: 'CDispatch'

Comment: If you're getting an error, please [edit] to include the full error traceback. I'm guessing from context that you're getting "The truth value of a series is ambiguous..." because you're trying to compare a single string to an entire column. What about `if sender in EmailList['Name']:`?

Comment: Thank You G. Anderson, with if sender in EmailList['Name']: I get error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'CDispatch'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/script.py", line 31, in <module>
    if sender in list3['Name']:
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1936, in __contains__
    return key in self._info_axis
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\numeric.py", line 211, in __contains__
    hash(key)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'CDispatch'

Comment: Hi  LZ75. What is the type of `sender`? I am not on windows so I can't replicate this part of your code. But  `EmailList ['Name'].str.contains(sender).any():` does the corrext thinf **if** I pass it a string!

Comment: Thanks dario:

type(sender)

returns:
Name: Name, dtype: object

Comment: @LZ75 But shouldn't 'sender` be a string? I am not quite sure but `Name: Name, dtype: object` looks to me like the series from `EmailList`?! Are you sure `sender` is the right object? What methods does it have? What is the output of `help(sender)`

Comment: I am getting sender from message.Sender from Outlook.

This is what help(sender) gave me...a really long text, but these are the 1st couple of rows:

Help on CDispatch in module win32com.client object:

class CDispatch(win32com.client.dynamic.CDispatch)
 |  CDispatch(IDispatch, olerepr, userName=None, UnicodeToString=None, lazydata=None)
 |  
 |  The dynamic class used as a last resort.
 |  The purpose of this overriding of dynamic.CDispatch is to perpetuate the policy
 |  of using the makepy generated wrapper Python class instead of dynamic.CDispatch
 |  if/when possible.

Comment: @LZ75 In the future, if you want to mark your question as solved, it is preferred if you use the answer your own question button instead of editing the post. By accepting an answer, it more visibly marks the question as having been completed and preserves the original question so others can refer to it later.

Comment: *Please* use that [edit] to add all relevant information **into your question**. Now all kinds of facts and clarifications are scattered among the comments.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!!

```py
sender = messages2.SenderName
```

&

```py
if EmailList['Name'].str.contains(sender).any():
```